# Save 3D data from the Kinect 2 to a .txt file

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2015, save, kinect

We want to use a Kinect 2 to get the 3D data from some models in a way for it to be treatable in Matlab. Basically a file with 3 columns with the X Y Z coordinates of the points measured by the Kinect. We don’t need a continuous video, a single “image” of the 3D points every time a button is clicked is enough.

There is sample code provided in the SDK that saves the data as an image (*Depth Basics-WPF*). All I want to do is to save the data as raw numbers in a .txt-file. Being new to C# I can’t find a way to do that. I tried saving it using different code found on google, but none seems to work.

The saving part of the code provided is as follows:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Handles the user clicking on the screenshot button
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">object sending the event</param>
    /// <param name="e">event arguments</param>
    private void ScreenshotdataButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.depthBitmap != null)
        {
            // create a png bitmap encoder which knows how to save a .png file
            BitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();

            // create frame from the writable bitmap and add to encoder
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(this.depthBitmap));

            string time = System.DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("hh'-'mm'-'ss", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat);

            string myPhotos = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);

            string path = Path.Combine(myPhotos, "KinectScreenshot-Depth-" + time + ".png");

            // write the new file to disk
            try
            {
                // FileStream is IDisposable
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    encoder.Save(fs);
                }

                this.StatusText = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, Properties.Resources.SavedScreenshotStatusTextFormat, path);
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                this.StatusText = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, Properties.Resources.FailedScreenshotStatusTextFormat, path);
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried reusing the code with a txt file as a target:

```
string datapath = Path.Combine(myPhotos, "KinectScreenshot-Depth-" + time + ".txt");
// FileStream is IDisposable
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(datapath, FileMode.Create))
{
    //File.WriteAllBytes(datapath, depthPixels);
    File.WriteAllText(datapath, depthRaw);
}
```

This doesn’t work, because *The name ‘depthRaw’ does not exist in current context.*.

I tried other ways with code found on google.

Version 1

```
public static Byte[] ImageToByteArray(Image img)
    {
        try
        {
            MemoryStream mstImage = new MemoryStream();
            img.Save(mstImage, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            Byte[] bytImage = mstImage.GetBuffer();
            return bytImage;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Version 2

```
public static byte[] ConvertToByteArray(WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            writeableBitmap.SaveJpeg(ms, writeableBitmap.PixelWidth, writeableBitmap.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Version 3

```
private byte[] ImageToByteArray (WriteableBitmap wbm)
    {
        using (Stream stream = wbm.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Version 4

```
string bitmapString = null;
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        depthBitmap.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.png);
        byte[] bitmapBytes = memoryStream.GetBuffer();
        bitmapString = Convert.ToBase64String(bitmapBytes, Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks);
    }
```

In all of those cases the compilation won’t even start either because *The type of namespace ‘Imaging’ does not exist in the namespace ‘System.Drawing’ (are you missing an assembly reference?)* or because *’WriteableBitmap’ does not contain a definition for ‘PixelBuffer’/‘SaveJpeg’/’Save’ and no extension method ‘PixelBuffer’/‘SaveJpeg’/’Save’ accepting a first argument of type ‘WriteableBitmap’ could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*.

My programming experience is limited to C and assembler. Maybe I’m just missing out some obvious part of C#? The program is made in C# in Visual Studio 2015 on a Windows PC with Windows 8.1 and Matlab 2011b.

Edit: the full code

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <copyright file="MainWindow.xaml.cs" company="Microsoft">
//     Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
// </copyright>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.DepthBasics
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
    using Microsoft.Kinect;

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Map depth range to byte range
        /// </summary>
        private const int MapDepthToByte = 8000 / 256;

        /// <summary>
        /// Active Kinect sensor
        /// </summary>
        private KinectSensor kinectSensor = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Reader for depth frames
        /// </summary>
        private DepthFrameReader depthFrameReader = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Description of the data contained in the depth frame
        /// </summary>
        private FrameDescription depthFrameDescription = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Bitmap to display
        /// </summary>
        private WriteableBitmap depthBitmap = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Intermediate storage for frame data converted to color
        /// </summary>
        private byte[] depthPixels = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Current status text to display
        /// </summary>
        private string statusText = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the MainWindow class.
        /// </summary>
        public MainWindow()
        {
            // get the kinectSensor object
            this.kinectSensor = KinectSensor.GetDefault();

            // open the reader for the depth frames
            this.depthFrameReader = this.kinectSensor.DepthFrameSource.OpenReader();

            // wire handler for frame arrival
            this.depthFrameReader.FrameArrived += this.Reader_FrameArrived;

            // get FrameDescription from DepthFrameSource
            this.depthFrameDescription = this.kinectSensor.DepthFrameSource.FrameDescription;

            // allocate space to put the pixels being received and converted
            this.depthPixels = new byte[this.depthFrameDescription.Width * this.depthFrameDescription.Height];

            // create the bitmap to display
            this.depthBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(this.depthFrameDescription.Width, this.depthFrameDescription.Height, 96.0, 96.0, PixelFormats.Gray8, null);

            // set IsAvailableChanged event notifier
            this.kinectSensor.IsAvailableChanged += this.Sensor_IsAvailableChanged;

            // open the sensor
            this.kinectSensor.Open();

            // set the status text
            this.StatusText = this.kinectSensor.IsAvailable ? Properties.Resources.RunningStatusText
                                                            : Properties.Resources.NoSensorStatusText;

            // use the window object as the view model in this simple example
            this.DataContext = this;

            // initialize the components (controls) of the window
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// INotifyPropertyChangedPropertyChanged event to allow window controls to bind to changeable data
        /// </summary>
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the bitmap to display
        /// </summary>
        public ImageSource ImageSource
        {
            get
            {
                return this.depthBitmap;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the current status text to display
        /// </summary>
        public string StatusText
        {
            get
            {
                return this.statusText;
            }

            set
            {
                if (this.statusText != value)
                {
                    this.statusText = value;

                    // notify any bound elements that the text has changed
                    if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                    {
                        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("StatusText"));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Execute shutdown tasks
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">object sending the event</param>
        /// <param name="e">event arguments</param>
        private void MainWindow_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.depthFrameReader != null)
            {
                // DepthFrameReader is IDisposable
                this.depthFrameReader.Dispose();
                this.depthFrameReader = null;
            }

            if (this.kinectSensor != null)
            {
                this.kinectSensor.Close();
                this.kinectSensor = null;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the user clicking on the screenshot button
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">object sending the event</param>
        /// <param name="e">event arguments</param>
        private void ScreenshotButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.depthBitmap != null)
            {
                // create a png bitmap encoder which knows how to save a .png file
                BitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();

                // create frame from the writable bitmap and add to encoder
                encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(this.depthBitmap));

                string time = System.DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("hh'-'mm'-'ss", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat);

                string myPhotos = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);

                string path = Path.Combine(myPhotos, "KinectScreenshot-Depth-" + time + ".png");

               // write the new file to disk
                try
                {
                    // FileStream is IDisposable
                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        encoder.Save(fs);
                    }

                    this.StatusText = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, Properties.Resources.SavedScreenshotStatusTextFormat, path);
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {
                    this.StatusText = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, Properties.Resources.FailedScreenshotStatusTextFormat, path);
                }
            }
        }

        /*public static Byte[] ImageToByteArray(Image img)
        {
            try
            {
                MemoryStream mstImage = new MemoryStream();
                img.Save(mstImage, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                Byte[] bytImage = mstImage.GetBuffer();
                return bytImage;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }*/

        /*public static byte[] ConvertToByteArray(WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                writeableBitmap.SaveJpeg(ms, writeableBitmap.PixelWidth, writeableBitmap.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }*/

        /*private byte[] ImageToByteArray (WriteableBitmap wbm)
        {
            using (Stream stream = wbm.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                return memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }*/


        /*byte[] ConvertBitmapToByteArray(WriteableBitmap bitmap)
        {
            using (Stream stream = bitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                return memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }*/

        /*string bitmapString = null;
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
        depthBitmap.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.png);
        byte[] bitmapBytes = memoryStream.GetBuffer();
        bitmapString = Convert.ToBase64String(bitmapBytes, Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks);
        }*/

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the user clicking on the screenshot button
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">object sending the event</param>
        /// <param name="e">event arguments</param>
        private void ScreenshotdataButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.depthBitmap != null)
            {
                WriteableBitmap deschd = this.depthBitmap;

                // create a png bitmap encoder which knows how to save a .png file
                BitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();

                // create frame from the writable bitmap and add to encoder
                encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(this.depthBitmap));

                string time = System.DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("hh'-'mm'-'ss", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat);

                string myPhotos = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);

                string path = Path.Combine(myPhotos, "KinectScreenshot-Depth-" + time + ".png");

                string datapath = Path.Combine(myPhotos, "KinectScreenshot-Depth-" + time + ".txt");

                // write the new file to disk
                try
                {
                    // FileStream is IDisposable
                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        encoder.Save(fs);
                    }

                    this.StatusText = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, Properties.Resources.SavedScreenshotStatusTextFormat, path);
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {
                    this.StatusText = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, Properties.Resources.FailedScreenshotStatusTextFormat, path);
                }

                // raw data

                //string depthRaw = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(this.depthPixels);
                string depthRaw = this.depthPixels.ToString();

                // write the txt file to disk with the raw data
                try
                {
                    // FileStream is IDisposable
                    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(datapath, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        //File.WriteAllBytes(datapath, depthPixels);
                        File.WriteAllText(datapath, depthRaw);
                    }

                    this.StatusText = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, Properties.Resources.SavedScreenshotStatusTextFormat, datapath);
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {
                    this.StatusText = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, Properties.Resources.FailedScreenshotStatusTextFormat, datapath);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the depth frame data arriving from the sensor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">object sending the event</param>
        /// <param name="e">event arguments</param>
        private void Reader_FrameArrived(object sender, DepthFrameArrivedEventArgs e)
        {
            bool depthFrameProcessed = false;

            using (DepthFrame depthFrame = e.FrameReference.AcquireFrame())
            {
                if (depthFrame != null)
                {
                    // the fastest way to process the body index data is to directly access 
                    // the underlying buffer
                    using (Microsoft.Kinect.KinectBuffer depthBuffer = depthFrame.LockImageBuffer())
                    {
                        // verify data and write the color data to the display bitmap
                        if (((this.depthFrameDescription.Width * this.depthFrameDescription.Height) == (depthBuffer.Size / this.depthFrameDescription.BytesPerPixel)) &&
                            (this.depthFrameDescription.Width == this.depthBitmap.PixelWidth) && (this.depthFrameDescription.Height == this.depthBitmap.PixelHeight))
                        {
                            // Note: In order to see the full range of depth (including the less reliable far field depth)
                            // we are setting maxDepth to the extreme potential depth threshold
                            ushort maxDepth = ushort.MaxValue;

                            // If you wish to filter by reliable depth distance, uncomment the following line:
                            //// maxDepth = depthFrame.DepthMaxReliableDistance

                            this.ProcessDepthFrameData(depthBuffer.UnderlyingBuffer, depthBuffer.Size, depthFrame.DepthMinReliableDistance, maxDepth);
                            depthFrameProcessed = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (depthFrameProcessed)
            {
                this.RenderDepthPixels();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Directly accesses the underlying image buffer of the DepthFrame to 
        /// create a displayable bitmap.
        /// This function requires the /unsafe compiler option as we make use of direct
        /// access to the native memory pointed to by the depthFrameData pointer.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="depthFrameData">Pointer to the DepthFrame image data</param>
        /// <param name="depthFrameDataSize">Size of the DepthFrame image data</param>
        /// <param name="minDepth">The minimum reliable depth value for the frame</param>
        /// <param name="maxDepth">The maximum reliable depth value for the frame</param>
        private unsafe void ProcessDepthFrameData(IntPtr depthFrameData, uint depthFrameDataSize, ushort minDepth, ushort maxDepth)
        {
            // depth frame data is a 16 bit value
            ushort* frameData = (ushort*)depthFrameData;

            // convert depth to a visual representation
            for (int i = 0; i < (int)(depthFrameDataSize / this.depthFrameDescription.BytesPerPixel); ++i)
            {
                // Get the depth for this pixel
                ushort depth = frameData[i];

                // To convert to a byte, we're mapping the depth value to the byte range.
                // Values outside the reliable depth range are mapped to 0 (black).
                this.depthPixels[i] = (byte)(depth >= minDepth && depth <= maxDepth ? (depth / MapDepthToByte) : 0);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Renders color pixels into the writeableBitmap.
        /// </summary>
        private void RenderDepthPixels()
        {
            this.depthBitmap.WritePixels(
                new Int32Rect(0, 0, this.depthBitmap.PixelWidth, this.depthBitmap.PixelHeight),
                this.depthPixels,
                this.depthBitmap.PixelWidth,
                0);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles the event which the sensor becomes unavailable (E.g. paused, closed, unplugged).
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">object sending the event</param>
        /// <param name="e">event arguments</param>
        private void Sensor_IsAvailableChanged(object sender, IsAvailableChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // on failure, set the status text
            this.StatusText = this.kinectSensor.IsAvailable ? Properties.Resources.RunningStatusText
                                                            : Properties.Resources.SensorNotAvailableStatusText;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my experience the Kinect SDK provides direct access to the depth values, so there is no need to get the bytes from an image

Comment: Please provide the full code ... icluding the `using` statements, i think you are missing some dll.

Comment: @Domysee In fact there is an explanation on how to get the depth data directly but they end up storing it as an image as well: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131029.aspx#CS_GetData

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. Using the fact that the color images have multiple bytes to store the data, I "expanded" the size of the grayscale:

```
private unsafe void ProcessDepthFrameData(IntPtr depthFrameData, uint depthFrameDataSize, ushort minDepth, ushort maxDepth)
{
    // depth frame data is a 16 bit value
    ushort* frameData = (ushort*)depthFrameData;

    int colorIndex = 0;

    // convert depth to a visual representation
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)(depthFrameDataSize / this.depthFrameDescription.BytesPerPixel); ++i)
    {
        // Get the depth for this pixel
        ushort depth = frameData[i];

        this.distanceImage[colorIndex++] = (byte)(depth >> 8); // how many times can the intensity be divided by 256?
        this.distanceImage[colorIndex++] = (byte)(depth - ((depth >> 8) << 8)); // remainder after the division
        this.distanceImage[colorIndex++] = (byte)(0);
        this.distanceImage[colorIndex++] = (byte)(255);

        // To convert to a byte, we're mapping the depth value to the byte range.
        // Values outside the reliable depth range are mapped to 0 (black).
        this.depthPixels[i] = (byte)(depth >= minDepth && depth <= maxDepth ? (depth / MapDepthToByte) : 0);
    }
}
```

This is then save as a color png. In Matlab the png is loaded and the inverse transformation executed to get one matrix with the depth values on the whole range.